# Microsoft update msu silent mode batchfile

Tags: batch-file

I have the MSU for Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64, which includes updates for PowerShell 5.0

I have a batchfile with the following to run the MSU in silent mode, but when I run it, it brings up the CMD window, then closes fast.

```
@echo off
start /wait ".\Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@echo off
start "" /wait "Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart
```

Comment: I did, and it says "Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64" make sure you typed it in correctly.

Comment: **_It actually also states that it cannot find a file with that name!_** You need to ensure that your batch file is in the same directory as your msu file when you double click it. Another alternative is to include the full path to your msu within the second set of double quotes.

Comment: It's in the same directory and folder

Comment: Have you tried using WUSA.EXE?   `@wusa.exe "Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart`   you should be able to forget about the start command with it's wait paramaeter.

Comment: So just to make sure, just type in exactly this?                                                                             @wusa.exe "Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart

Comment: Yes, WUSA.EXE should be in your PATH by default, so as long as your current directory contains the MSU file it should be silently installed.

Comment: Thank you, I typed that and it's doing the same thing, opening and closing fast without installing the .msu

Comment: You may have a corrupt msu file! Your version of WMF 5.0, Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu should be 20.8 MB in size and requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 or above. To check the version of .NET you are running, enter the following in a command window `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" /v Version`

Comment: I'll try downloading it again.  I was able to install it manually, so I don't think it's a corrupt file.  I have NET Framework version 4.5.51209